# Length of curve in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to compute the length of a generic curve in TikZ?

An answer to this question would solve [TikZ dashes and closed curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214400/tikz-dashes-and-closed-curves) as follows: Let `lc` be the length of the curve and `lp` the desired length of the dash pattern. All we have to do is rescale the dash pattern to the length `lc/round(lc/lp)`.

Comment: The decoration module provides some internal macros for approximating the length of the curve. But considering the application, possibly your question is answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133357).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Improved version:

You can use a decoration and `\pgfdecoratedpathlength`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
    measureme/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 1 with {\node[below,black,anchor=west] {My length is \pgfdecoratedpathlength};},
    },
    postaction=decorate
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
\coordinate (A); 
\coordinate (B) at (20pt,0);
\draw[cyan,measureme] (A) -- (B);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
\coordinate (A); 
\coordinate (B) at (20pt,0);
\draw[cyan,measureme] (A) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=10pt];
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm]
\coordinate (A); 
\coordinate (B) at (20pt,0);
\draw[cyan,measureme] (A) .. controls(0.25,2) and (0.75,-2) .. (B);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
\coordinate (A); 
\coordinate (B) at (20pt,0);
\draw[cyan,measureme] (A) .. controls(0.25,7) and (0.75,-7) .. (B);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Initial version:

Here's an option using decorations and the `distance from start` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
    measureme/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position -.01pt with {%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}\@totallength
            \global\let\@totallength\@totallength
        },
        mark=at position 0 with {\node[black] {\@totallength};},
    },
    postaction=decorate
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A); 
\coordinate (B) at (20pt,0);
\draw[cyan,measureme] (A) -- (B);
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\coordinate (A); 
\coordinate (B) at (20pt,0);
\draw[cyan,measureme] (A) .. controls(0.25,2) and (0.75,-2) .. (B);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\coordinate (A); 
\coordinate (B) at (20pt,0);
\draw[cyan,measureme] (A) .. controls(0.25,7) and (0.75,-7) .. (B);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I implement these very nice solutions sometimes I get the length and when the shape of the Bezier changes, ie different endpoint, then the length do not show!!! What happens?