# Overfull \hbox with a tabular TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, minipage, badness

Compiling my .tex file in TeXnicCenter,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{->-/.style={semithick,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .52 with {\arrow{Stealth[length=2.5mm]}}},
        postaction={decorate}}}

\tikzset{--<--/.style={semithick,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .28 with {\arrow{Stealth[length=2.5mm]}}},
    postaction={decorate}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cp{1cm}c}
$A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$; &  &  
$\Gamma(A_1)\equiv \;\;\;\;\;$  

\begin{minipage}{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.725]

    \coordinate [label=below left:$P_1$] (p1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$P_2$] (p2) at (6cm,0);

    \filldraw (p1) circle [radius=0.08cm]
              (p2) circle [radius=0.08cm];

    \draw[->-] (0,0) to [bend left] (6cm,0);

    \draw[->-] (p1) to [bend left] (p2);

    \draw[->-] (p2) to [bend left] (p1);

    \draw[--<--,rotate=60] (p2) arc (360:0:-1cm and -0.5cm);

    \draw[--<--,rotate=120] (p1) arc (0:360:-1cm and -0.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

you get 1 bad box and the following message in Build Output:

```
pdflatex> Overfull \hbox (147.05411pt to wide) in paragraph at line 50--51
```

How can I get rid of them without removing the tabular?

[image]

Comment: you declare the width of the `minipage` to be 1cm, however image inside is at least 6cm wide. consequently you receive mentioned warning. welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the minipage, I think. The complaint was because the minipage was not wide enough to fit the picture, as pointed out by Zarko.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{->-/.style={semithick,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .52 with {\arrow{Stealth[length=2.5mm]}}},
        postaction={decorate}}}

\tikzset{--<--/.style={semithick,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .28 with {\arrow{Stealth[length=2.5mm]}}},
    postaction={decorate}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cp{1cm}c}
$A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$; &  &  
$\Gamma(A_1)\equiv \;\;\;\;\;$  

%\begin{minipage}{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.725,baseline=(p1)]

    \coordinate [label=below left:$P_1$] (p1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$P_2$] (p2) at (6cm,0);

    \filldraw (p1) circle [radius=0.08cm]
              (p2) circle [radius=0.08cm];

    \draw[->-] (0,0) to [bend left] (6cm,0);

    \draw[->-] (p1) to [bend left] (p2);

    \draw[->-] (p2) to [bend left] (p1);

    \draw[--<--,rotate=60] (p2) arc (360:0:-1cm and -0.5cm);

    \draw[--<--,rotate=120] (p1) arc (0:360:-1cm and -0.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

%\end{minipage}

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

And actually I would not use a tabular either. And I add some other features, some of which are suggested by Zarko (Thanks!).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\usetikzlibrary{bending} %< added
\tikzset{% inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316050/121799
    arc arrow/.style args={%
    to pos #1 with length #2}{
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{#2/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=#2,bend]}]       
        (@1) .. controls (@2) and (@3) .. (@4);},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     }
}


\tikzset{->-/.style={semithick,arc arrow={to pos 0.52 with length 2.5mm}}}

\tikzset{--<--/.style={semithick,arc arrow={to pos 0.28 with length 2.5mm}}}
\begin{document}

\[
A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \quad\text{with}~
\Gamma(A_1)\equiv \quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.725,baseline=(p1)]
    \coordinate [label=below left:$P_1$] (p1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$P_2$] (p2) at (6cm,0);
    \filldraw (p1) circle [radius=0.08cm]
              (p2) circle [radius=0.08cm];
    \draw[->-] (p1) to [bend left] (p2);
    \draw[->-] (p1) to [bend left] (p2);
    \draw[->-] (p2) to [bend left] (p1);
    \draw[--<--,rotate=60] (p2) arc (360:0:-1cm and -0.5cm);
    \draw[--<--,rotate=120] (p1) arc (0:360:-1cm and -0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other options to center the `tikzpicture` include wrapping it into `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! There are additional improvements possible, I think, but the output is already decent, so why changing a code the OP created and is comfortable with?

Comment: you are right. actually, i'm surprised that y comment appear. at writing it some magic happens and and i lost it on my screen, so i believe, that it is not uploaded ... anyway, i will delete it now.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks again. I added some of your suggestions....

Comment: How could I remove the bad box with my minipage?

Comment: @IgnacioT I guess you only need to make it wider, e.g. `\begin{minipage}{7cm}` or so. But why do you want to keep it?

Comment: Sorry, what I really want to keep is the tabular.

Comment: @IgnacioT The upper code of my answer has the tabular.