# Drawing arrows on the curves lines (transition diagram)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, transition

I am trying to replicate the transition diagram below:

[image: desired output]

So far, I have managed draw all lines and labelled my nodes with the codes below:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[a/.style = {insert new path = {-triangle 90}}]
%\draw[thick] (0,0) --+ (1,3) --+ (5,3) --+ (4,0) --+ (0,0);
%\draw[thick] (0,0) --+ (1,1.73) --+ (3,1.73) --+ (4,0)--+ (3,-1.73)--+ (1,-1.73)--+ (0,0);
%
\draw[thick,fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5mm);
\draw[thick,fill=black] (5,0) circle (1.5mm);
\draw[thick,fill=black] (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5mm);
%
\node [left] at (-0.15, 0.2) {$C$};
\node [right] at (5.2,0.2) {$S$};
\node [below] at (2.5,-3.7) {$T$};
%\node [right] at (4, 0) {$X$};
%\node [below] at (3, -1.73) {$Y$};
%\node [below] at (1, -1.73) {$Z$};
%
\draw[thick](-0.6,0.5) circle (0.8cm);
\draw[thick](0,0) to [bend right=20](5,0);
\draw[thick](0,0) to [bend left=20](5,0);
%
\draw[thick](5.6,0.5) circle (0.8cm);
\draw[thick](0,0) to [bend right=20](2.5,-3.5);
\draw[thick](0,0) to [bend left=20](2.5,-3.5);
%
\draw[thick](2.5,-4.27) circle (0.8cm);
\draw[thick](5,0) to [bend right=20](2.5,-3.5);
\draw[thick](5,0) to [bend left=20](2.5,-3.5);
%
%\draw[thick,opacity=0.7,fill=black] (2.5,1.5) circle (0.5mm);
%\node[above] at (2.5,1.65) {$M$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image: got this]

Could anyone experienced please tell me how I can insert these arrows on the curves?

Thank you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39278/tikz-arrowheads-in-the-center

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better arrow orientation in curves can be done using decorations.markings, which allows you to insert any drawing along a path; then I simplified your code using all the options available by command.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    %Environment config
    %Environment Styles
    Circ/.style={circle, fill, minimum width=12pt},
    MidArrow/.style={
        draw,thick, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\fill(0:5pt) -- (120:5pt) -- (240:5pt);}}}}
    ]

    %Drawing the nodes
    %\node[tikzstyle, label=angle_orientation:Text](Node_coordinate_Identifier) at (position_in_polar_coordinates){Text_none};
    \node[Circ, label=30:$S$](S) at (30:2.5){};
    \node[Circ, label=150:$P$](P) at (150:2.5){};
    \node[Circ, label=270:$T$](T) at (270:2.5){};

    %Drawing the arrows
    \draw[MidArrow] (P) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=-90, inner sep=8pt]{40\%} (S);
    \draw[MidArrow] (S) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=-90, inner sep=6pt]{20\%} (P);
    \draw[MidArrow] (P) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=50, inner sep=4pt]{20\%} (T);
    \draw[MidArrow] (T) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=30, inner sep=4pt]{20\%} (P);
    \draw[MidArrow] (T) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=-60, inner sep=8pt]{20\%} (S);
    \draw[MidArrow] (S) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=180, inner sep=6pt]{20\%} (T);
    \draw[MidArrow] (P) arc (150-180:150-180-360:0.8) node [midway, anchor=150-180,inner sep=4pt]{40\%};
    \draw[MidArrow] (S) arc (30-180:30-180-360:0.8) node [midway, anchor=30-180,inner sep=4pt]{60\%};
    \draw[MidArrow] (T) arc (270-180:270-180-360:0.8)node [midway, anchor=270-180,inner sep=6pt]{60\%};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### UPDATE:

Adding the possibility to control the arrow head position in the curves; then control the label position using the option `pos={0_to_1_value}` instead `midway` that is equivalent to `pos=0.5`, and \sf to get serif font for percent symbol to reproduce a result more similar to the example,demonstrating the great flexibility provided by basic tikz commands.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    %Environment config
    %Environment Styles
    Circ/.style={circle, fill, minimum width=12pt},
    InLineArrow/.style={
        draw,thick, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\fill(0:5pt) -- (120:5pt) -- (240:5pt);}}}}
    ]

    %Drawing the nodes
    %\node[tikzstyle, label=angle_orientation:Text](Node_coordinate_Identifier) at (position_in_polar_coordinates){Text_none};
    \node[Circ, label=30:$S$](S) at (30:2.5){};
    \node[Circ, label=150:$P$](P) at (150:2.5){};
    \node[Circ, label=270:$T$](T) at (270:2.5){};

    %Drawing the arrows
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (P) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=-90, inner sep=8pt]{40\sf\%} (S);
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (S) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=-90, inner sep=6pt]{20\sf\%} (P);
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (P) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=50, inner sep=4pt]{20\sf\%} (T);
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (T) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=30, inner sep=4pt]{20\sf\%} (P);
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (T) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=-60, inner sep=8pt]{20\sf\%} (S);
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (S) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=180, inner sep=6pt]{20\sf\%} (T);
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.41] (P) arc (150-180:150-180-360:0.8) node [pos=0.41, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{40\sf\%};
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.58] (S) arc (30-180:30-180-360:0.8) node [pos=0.58, anchor=0-180,inner sep=7pt]{60\sf\%};
    \draw[InLineArrow=0.75] (T) arc (270-180:270-180-360:0.8)node [pos=0.65, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{60\sf\%};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @J_Leon_V.: What about the arrows in the circle?

Comment: They are tangent to the circle from the barycenter, not from the tip as in your MWE, which causes the base to be very out of phase with the arrow line.

Answer (score 8):

Definitely not the best answer, but it works:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39278/tikz-arrowheads-in-the-center
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 60]
        \begin{scope}[a/.style = {insert new path = {-triangle 90}}]
                \draw[thick,fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5mm);
                \draw[thick,fill=black] (5,0) circle (1.5mm);
                \draw[thick,fill=black] (2.5,-3.5) circle (1.5mm);
                    \node [left] at (-0.15, 0.2) {$C$};
                    \node [right] at (5.2,0.2) {$S$};
                    \node [below] at (2.5,-3.7) {$T$};
                \draw[->-=.5,thick](.2,0.5) arc(0:-360:.8cm);
                \draw[->-=.5,thick](5,0) to [bend left=20](0,0);
                \draw[->-=.5,thick](0,0) to [bend left=20](5,0);
                \draw[xshift=11.25cm,xscale=-1,->-=.5,thick](5.6,0.5) circle (0.8cm);
                    \draw[->-=.5,thick](2.5,-3.5) to [bend left=20](0,0);
                    \draw[->-=.5,thick](0,0) to [bend left=20](2.5,-3.5);
                    \draw[yscale=-1,yshift=8.55cm,->-=.5,thick](2.5,-4.27) circle (0.8cm);
                    \draw[->-=.5,thick](2.5,-3.5) to [bend left=20](5,0);
                \draw[->-=.5,thick](5,0) to [bend left=20](2.5,-3.5);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT:** Just replace some `[… ->-=.5 …]` with `[… ->-=.55 …]` to get the arrow heads on the “exact place“ (the whole arrowhead is merging with the one below).

Answer (score 5):

After imgur recovered I could see the desired output. I'd like to argue that the arrows become slightly nicer

- when the arrows get bent
- one uses symbolic coordinates that are arranged more symmetically
- and allows for arbitrary positions.

Otherwise this post has substantial overlap with the other great answers.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
% inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316050/121799
% and further developed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430239/121799
\tikzset{
    arc arrow/.style args={%
    to pos #1 and length #2 and label #3}{
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{#2/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Triangle[bend,length=#2]}]       
        (@1) .. controls (@2) and (@3) .. (@4)
        node[pos=0.8,auto,font=\sffamily]{#3};},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[thick]
%
\draw[fill=black] (150:3.5) coordinate[label={[above left=2pt]P}] (P) circle (1.5mm);
\draw[fill=black] (30:3.5) coordinate[label={[above right=2pt]S}] (S) circle (1.5mm);
\draw[fill=black] (-90:3.5) coordinate[label={[below=2pt]T}] (T) circle (1.5mm);
%
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.45 and length 3mm and label {40\,\%}](P) arc(-30:-390:0.8cm);
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.5 and length 3mm and label {20\,\%}](P) to [bend left=20] (T);
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.5 and length 3mm and label {20\,\%}](T) to [bend left=20] (P);
%
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.65 and length 3mm and label {60\,\%}](S) arc(210:-150:0.8cm);
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.5 and length 3mm and label {20\,\%}](S) to [bend left=20] (P);
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.5 and length 3mm and label {40\,\%}](P) to [bend left=20] (S);
%
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.7 and length 3mm and label {60\,\%}](T) arc(90:-270:0.8cm);
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.5 and length 3mm and label {20\,\%}](T) to [bend left=20] (S);
\draw[arc arrow=to pos 0.5 and length 3mm and label {20\,\%}](S) to [bend left=20] (T);
%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Be careluf with the arrows. ;)

Comment: This is really good. But do you think you can make the arrows be in triangular shape?

Comment: @Will_Kim: just ad ```\begin{tikzpicture][>=triangle 60] …```; see also my answer, but marmot's answer is better …

Comment: @WillKim Just replace `Stealth[]` by `Triangle[]`. If you want to reverse it, use `Triangle[reversed]`.  The full set of options for the Triangle arrow is described on p. 210 of the pgfmanual. (current_user: Thanks!)

Answer (score 5):

One can define an arrow style in Ti*k*z. I used the idea from [this answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39283/125434)

Put `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` in the preamble and write the following code right below `\begin{document}`

```
\tikzset{middlearrow/.style={
        decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{#1}} ,
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}
```

And then, write the parameter `middlearrow={'type of arrow here'}`. I used `stealth reversed`.

[image]