# How to draw multiple curved arrowheads

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I try to use tikz to draw the arrows like the blue ones, but so far I can draw only the red one and it is not as expected. Here my code so far, it is time consuming so please if anyone has better solutions to draw the blue ones. Thanks.

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->,very thick] (0,6) -- (0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw [->, thick,red] (3.8,1.7)  -- (3.6,1.8);
\draw [->,thick,red] (6,6) to [out=110,in=-20] (5.75,6.25);
\draw [->,thick,red] (5.75,6.25) to[out=160,in=-20] (5.5,6.35);
\draw [->,thick,red] (5.5,6.35) to[out=160,in=50] (5,6.10);
\draw [->,thick,red] (5,6.10) to[out=-130,in=60] (4.75,5.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: see of `decorations.markins` can help you. see second example on page 636, tikz & pgf manual, v 3.1.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bend arrows, and with the `arc arrow` style you can place them along a path such that they get bent along the path, and the `/.list` key allows you to draw several of them. With these preparations you may cook down the code to something like

```
\draw[red,very thick,my arrow/.list={0.2,0.45,0.7},-{Stealth[length=2mm,bend]}] 
 (6,6) to [out=110,in=60,looseness=1.4] (4.75,5.75);
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.markings}
% source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430239/121799
\tikzset{% inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316050/121799
    arc arrow/.style args={%
    to pos #1 with length #2}{
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{#2/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=#2,bend]}]       
        (@1) .. controls (@2) and (@3) .. (@4);},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my arrow/.style={arc arrow=to pos #1 with length 2mm}]
 \draw[red,very thick,my arrow/.list={0.2,0.45,0.7},-{Stealth[length=2mm,bend]}] 
 (6,6) to [out=110,in=60,looseness=1.4] (4.75,5.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, in case you want these gaps, you could use the `show path construction` decoration.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.pathreplacing}
% source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430239/121799
\tikzset{multiple arrows/.style={decorate,decoration={show path construction,
 curveto code={
      \draw [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast);
    },}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [multiple arrows={red,thick,-{Stealth[length=2mm,bend]}}] 
(6,6) to [out=110,in=-20] (5.75,6.25)
 to[out=160,in=-20] (5.5,6.35) to[out=160,in=50] (5,6.10) 
 to[out=-130,in=60] (4.75,5.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]