# Starparalax Help

Tags: diagrams

I'm pretty new to Latex and i've just found out about tikZ. I'm barely able to make a triangle and angle. I just wanted to ask if you can tell me how to start with he following project:[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_parallax#/media/File:Stellarparallax_parsec1.svg]

The Preamble:

```
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.markings,intersections,angles,quotes,babe        l,lindenmayersystems,plotmarks}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{A}{%
  \symbol{F}{\pgflsystemstep=0.6\pgflsystemstep\pgflsystemdrawforward}
  \rule{A->F[+A][-A]}
}
\tikzset{
    arc arrow/.style args={%
    to pos 1 with length 2}{
    decoration={
    markings,
     mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{2/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
     \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
    mark=at position {1-\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
    mark=at position {1-2*\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@2);},
    mark=at position {1-\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@3);},
    mark=at position {1} with {\coordinate(@4);
    \draw[-{Stealth[length=2,bend]}]       
    (@1) .. controls (@2) and (@3) .. (@4);},
    },
 postaction=decorate,
 },bent arrow/.style={arc arrow=to pos #1 with length 2mm},
 pics/strange bar/.style={code={\draw[thick] (-#1,0) -- (#1,0);}}
}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä}, germandbls={ß}}
```

The Frame:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \draw[name path=A] (0,5) coordinate(TL) -- (0,0);
    \draw[bent arrow/.list={0.125,0.625}] (0,0) circle[x radius=2cm,y radius=0.5cm];
    \draw[fill=blue] (-2,0) circle[radius=1.5mm];
    \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) circle[radius=2mm];
    \draw[name path=B] (-2,0) -- (1,5) coordinate(TR);
    \draw[fill=pink,name intersections={of=A and B,by=I}] (I) circle[radius=1.5mm]node[left=3pt]{Near star};
    \pic [angle radius=1cm,angle eccentricity=.5,draw,"p" alias=p] {angle = TR--I--TL};
     \draw[pink,latex-,thick] (p) -- ++ (1,-1) node[right,align=left,text=black]{parallax angle\\ = 1``};
    \draw ([xshift=5mm]I) -- ++ (3,0) coordinate (R1) pic[rotate=45]{strange bar=0.3}
    -- (0,0-|R1) coordinate (R2)  pic[rotate=45]{strange bar=0.3}node[midway,above,sloped] {1 parsec}
    -- (2.5,0); 
    \draw (-2,-0.3) -- (-2,-2) pic[rotate=45]{strange bar=0.3} -- (0,-2)node[midway,above]{1 AE} pic[rotate=45]{strange bar=0.3}
    -- (0,-0.3);
    \draw[bent arrow/.list={0.125,0.625},thin] (0,5)  circle[x radius=1cm,y radius=0.15cm];
    \draw[fill=pink] (TR) circle[radius=1mm] (-1,5) circle[radius=1mm];
    \draw[pink,latex-,thick,shorten >=1mm] (TR) -- ++ (0.5,-1) node[right,align=left,text=black] (AP) {apparent parallax\\ motion near star};
    \draw[pink,latex-,thick,shorten >=1mm] (-1,5) -- (AP.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! This is to give you a start. I apologize in advance if I have misinterpreted some elements.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.markings,intersections,angles,quotes}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430239/121799
\tikzset{% inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316050/121799
    arc arrow/.style args={%
    to pos #1 with length #2}{
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{#2/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=#2,bend]}]       
        (@1) .. controls (@2) and (@3) .. (@4);},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },bent arrow/.style={arc arrow=to pos #1 with length 2mm},
     pics/strange bar/.style={code={\draw[thick] (-#1,0) -- (#1,0);}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \draw[semithick] (80:12) arc(80:100:12) node[midway,above]{Distant stars};
 \fill foreach \X in {82,86,90,92,95,99} {(\X:12) circle[radius=1.5pt] };
 \draw[name path=A] (0,11.8) coordinate(TL) -- (0,0);
 \draw[bent arrow/.list={0.125,0.625}] (0,0) circle[x radius=2cm,y radius=0.5cm];
 \draw[fill=blue] (-2,0) circle[radius=2mm];
 \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) circle[radius=2mm];
 \draw[name path=B] (-2,0) -- (1,11.8) coordinate(TR);
 \draw[fill=pink,name intersections={of=A and B,by=I}] (I) circle[radius=2mm]
 node[left=3pt]{Near star};
 \pic [angle radius=1cm,angle eccentricity=1.3,draw,"p" alias=p] {angle = TR--I--TL};
 \draw[pink,latex-,thick] (p) -- ++ (1,-0.5) node[right,align=left,text=black]{parallax angle};
 \draw ([xshift=5mm]I) -- ++ (3,0) coordinate (R1) pic[rotate=45]{strange bar=0.6}
 -- (0,0-|R1) coordinate (R2)  pic[rotate=45]{strange bar=0.6}
 node[midway,above,sloped] {1 parsec}
 -- (2.5,0); 
 \draw (-2,-0.3) -- (-2,-2) pic[rotate=45]{strange bar=0.6} -- (0,-2)
 node[midway,above]{1 AU} pic[rotate=45]{strange bar=0.6}
 -- (0,-0.3);
 \draw[bent arrow/.list={0.125,0.625},thin] (0,11.8)  circle[x radius=1cm,y radius=0.15cm];
 \draw[fill=pink] (TR) circle[radius=1mm] (-1,11.8) circle[radius=1mm];
 \draw[pink,latex-,thick,shorten >=1mm] (TR) -- ++ (0.5,-1) 
 node[right,align=left,text=black] (AP) {apparent parallax\\ motion near star};
 \draw[pink,latex-,thick,shorten >=1mm] (-1,11.8) -- (AP.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much

Comment: I get following error: I do not know the key '\tikz\"p�lias', to which you passed 'p', and I am going to ignore it. So the name of the angle isn't shown and the arrow (paralax angle) points on the sun. But thank you very much for providing the whole code!

Comment: @TirolaleinLeine Do you compile the above document when you get the error or do you get it when you embed the tikzpicture in another document? In the latter case, does the error go away if you add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to the preamble of your document?

Comment: its embeded in my document and i still have the error when in add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. I tried to post my whole preamble but its too long. Something special you would need?

Comment: @TirolaleinLeine In that case you may just ask a new question with a minimal example (a minimal document with the preamble of the embedding document and the code of the picture you are using).

Comment: I haved added the preamble and the code of the frame to the question.

Comment: @TirolaleinLeine You need a fragile frame: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: @samcarter What does it change?

Comment: @TirolaleinLeine It makes your code compilable by preventing some voodoo tha beamer normally does with all content of a frame

Comment: @TirolaleinLeine In this particular case the problem probably are the `#` in the tikzset

Comment: @Samcarter yeah now its prefect.

Comment: @TirolaleinLeine What happened here is a good example that illustrates why many users here ask for an MWE (minimal working example). If you would have provided one (even if the `tikzpicture` was very minimal), anyone answering it would circumvented the pitfalls (and also made sure that the thingy fits on a beamer slide). Changing these things afterwards is a bit cumbersome, and many users are not really willing to do that.

Comment: @marmot I recently cleaned my crystal ball for the upcoming spring and now it works again for such problems :)