# Use of @ in coordinate names (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I was writing some macros for drawing timelines in Tikz and thought that it might be good to name the internal help coordinates with an @ in it.
The idea is that in this way it will not conflict with the coordinates of a potential user of those macros (not that I will be able to produce a package because of my recurrent [coding problems](https://xkcd.com/2138/)).

However, I was surprised that I can use an @ in the name of a coordinate without placing it within `\makeatletter` and `\makatother`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)--(2,0) coordinate (A@1);
  \draw (1,1)--(A@1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My question is: why does it work?

Then, if the @ can be used freely, the help coordinates will not be protected against an unintentional use.

Comment: The fact that one can use `@` in coordinate names is well known and has used e.g. in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316050/121799. The idea is still that using these makes it less likely that "random users" accidentally use the same symbols. Same is true for underscores, e.g. `\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) --(2,0) coordinate (A@1) (4,0) coordinate (X_Y);
  \draw (1,1)--(A@1) -- (X_Y);
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the distinction between letters and non letters (catcode 11 or not) is just when parsing after the escape character (usually `\`) so `\foo@bar` normally parses as the 5 tokens `\foo`, `@`, `b`, `a`, `r`.  But the `foo@bar` csname can be accessed without changing the catcode of `@`  by using `\csname foo@bar\endcsname` for example.

You see a similar thing with environment names where `\begin{tabular*}` access the command with name `tabular*` even though `\tabular*` would not access that  but the two tokens `\tabular` and `*` unless you change the catcode of `*` to 11.

Comment: So the coordinate names are converted to commands through \csname?

Comment: @RaoulKessels most likely, but whatever tikz does with them, the catcode status of `@` has no effect on anything but the parsing of `\abc@xyz`  so it will not affect the use you show with `coordinate (A@1)`  (well other than explicit testing with `\ifcat` )