# Double line edge using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-graphdrawing, qtree

How do I draw such tree like this

[image]

where the some of the edges are double lines using TikZ or any other package?

Here is the code:

```
\Tree [.root [.a (i want here to have double edge line)b [.b c ] ] [.a [ .b c ] [.b d [.c [.d d ] ]] ] ]
```

Comment: I looked up https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224798/tikz-double-line-one-dashed this example but its too complicated for my simple tree.

Comment: I planned to only use `\Tree` to build the tree but I am not sure where i should add the function to have double edge line.

Comment: Add the code without the double line so that we can have a look and add it

Comment: I have added @JouleV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `forest` it is easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{my dbl/.style={double,double distance=2pt}}
\begin{forest}
for tree={edge=thick,calign=fixed edge angles}
[a
 [b,edge=my dbl
  [b
   [b
    [c]
   ]
   [c,edge=my dbl]
  ]
  [*
   [c,edge=my dbl]
  ]
 ] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`tikz-cd` can do the trick

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.4cm,row sep=0.4cm]
& & a \arrow[d,equal] & \\
& & b \arrow[rd,dash]\arrow[ld,dash] & \\
& b \arrow[rd,equal]\arrow[ld,dash] & & * \arrow[d,equal] \\
b \arrow[d,dash] & & c & c\\
c & & &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JouleV .