# How to draw an arc in Tikz that has gaps specifically placed in it

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I was wondering how I could draw an arc in Tikz that has small gaps in it in a simple way, like this:

[image: The arc]

Here is working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (6,2.5) arc (0:180:4cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The gaps need not be of different lengths.

Much appreciated,

Alex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would using `\draw[loosely dashed]` or some suitably-defined custom dash pattern work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the `dash pattern` style on your path with `on` and `off` pairs:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dash pattern=on 1.5cm off 1cm on 1cm off 1cm on 1cm off .5cm on 1cm off .5cm]
    (6,2.5) arc (0:180:4cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: The on-and-off pairs technique solves my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

According to the pgfmanual section *15.3.2 Graphic Parameters: Dash Pattern*, you have several possibilities:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\draw[dashed] (6,2.5) arc (0:180:4cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\draw[loosely dashed] (6,2.5) arc (0:180:4cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\draw[dash pattern=on 6mm off 7mm] (6,2.5) arc (0:180:4cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: For a solution to the well know issue at the two ends of the line, please refer to [Can TikZ dashed lines emulate PSTricks dashed lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133271/13304).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, salviati's solution solves the problem by allowing more specific placement of the gaps I need in the arc.

Comment: @Alex: You're welcome and remember that you can always select to accept the answer that fully satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `dash pattern` key option of `tikz` has been borrowed from MetaPost: the syntax is exactly the same. I couldn't let this pass without reacting, so for the sake of justice here is Salviati's example translated in `tikz`'s original language :-)

```
beginfig(1);
    draw halfcircle xscaled (8cm) yscaled (2cm) 
        dashed dashpattern(on 1.5cm off 1cm on 1cm off 1cm on 1cm off .5cm on 1cm off .5cm);
endfig;
end.
```

[image]